# Couchbase 5 memcache bucket not getting flushed

Tags: java, couchbase

I am using Couchbase 5 and I have a Couchbase memcache bucket created , while creating bucket I checked Flush option , but still when I try to flush my memcache bucket it is not working. I am doing that operation via Couchbase UI.

Comment: Try flushing the bucket from the cli. That will tell you whether or not the UI is the problem. https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/cli/cbcli/bucket-flush.html

Comment: How do you know it is not working? Are you looking at `items` or `disk used` column? Is there more than 1 node? If so - do you have any replicas?

Comment: I have installed couchbas eon my machine and then I am trying to perform this operation but items are not getting flushed.